# how to do open a link in a open window from menu bar?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a word press site.

When I click on a entry in menu bar, it should open that link in a new window.

I know how to do this for a button but not sure for a list item.

This is the code I would use to open it in a new window for a button.

```
function myImg()

{
    window.name = "thiswin";

    newwin=open("", "dispwin", 

    "width=750,height=300,scrollbars=no, menubar=no");

     var otherWebsiteURL = "http://www.google.com";

     newwin.document.write("<div><a href='"+otherWebsiteURL+"'><img    
src='"+imagePath+"'></a></div>");
}
```

I have already checked the option to open in new window/tab  in the menu editor. It is now opening in a new tab.

But, I want to open it in new window.

This is my site: http://classichits.ie/ and I want to do this on "listen live" in the menu bar.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below code to bottom of your functions.php, I have replaced with your menu item ID

```
function lidget_popup_link() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        var width = "680", /* Enter popup window width here */
            height = "480", /* Enter popup window height here */
            menuItem = "menu-item-140", /* Enter menu item ID */
            target = "#"+menuItem+" a",
            hrefVal = jQuery(target).attr("href")
        ;
        jQuery(target).attr({
            "href" : "#",
            "onclick" : "window.open('"+hrefVal+"','','width="+width+",height="+height+",scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no')"
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'lidget_popup_link');

function lidget_call_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lidget_call_jquery');
?>
```

For details please follow [wordpress.org support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/open-external-link-within-a-defined-pop-up-window)

OUTPUT (contact page open in pop up):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got this error, 

**bold** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/classichits/public_html/wp-content/themes/4fm/functions.php on line 405 **bold**

This is basically the one right after `code`<?php`code`

Comment: Its syntax error, may when you pasted code. Otherwise its working like screenshot in answer. Please check code when you paste in you functions.php

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tKY1kN9D This is my whole functions.php code.

I exactly did what you suggested, pasted it at the very end of the file. 

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: start <?php before "function lidget_popup_link() {" or please use this one http://pastebin.com/r3kyPJ9W

Comment: no luck. still the same error.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont have much knowledge, so please bear with me. 

can you please paste the code with the edit you just suggested. thanks.

Comment: No problem, please try using this code   http://pastebin.com/r3kyPJ9W

Comment: I am glad that it works!

Comment: I am getting this error now, when I am updating my pages and posts. 
I wasn't getting this before the above edit. Please help me **bold**   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/classichits/public_html/wp-content/themes/4fm/functions.php:388) in /home/classichits/public_html/wp-admin/post.php on line 197 
**bold**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/classichits/public_html/wp-content/themes/4fm/functions.php:388) in /home/classichits/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Comment: I have commented why error is there in your started chat discussion link. But now I am not able to see chat link here ?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I deleted it by mistake. Here it is http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34647/discussion-between-nauman-tanwir-and-jas